# How do I focus image from the center (CSS focus)?

Tags: html, css, image, focus, gallery

I got the left image to focus from the left(default) and right image focus from the right.

```
a:nth-child(3) img{
right: 0;
}
```

But how do I make the center image focus from the center?
Also, is there a way to make all images focus from the same place (middle of the page or do I have to use some other technique for that all together(html/css only)? Finally, is there a better technique for building this type of gallery?(html/css only)

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/alexdj1983/pen/NPZMre)

Thank you.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="thumb_main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Thumbnails Gallery</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="gallery">
<a tabindex="1"><img src="ball.jpg">
</a>
<a tabindex="1"><img src="ball.jpg">
</a>
<a tabindex="1"><img src="ball.jpg">
</a>
<a tabindex="1"><img src="ball.jpg">
</a>
<a tabindex="1"><img src="ball.jpg">
</a>
<a tabindex="1"><img src="ball.jpg">
</a>
<a tabindex="1"><img src="ball.jpg">
</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
margin: 0;}

.gallery{
margin:20px auto;
width:900px;
height:900px;
position:relative;
}

a {
float:left;
position: relative;
width:30%;
height:30%;
border: 1px solid black;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

a img{
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-transition-duration: 300ms; 
-moz-transition-duration: 300ms;
-o-transition-duration: 300ms;
position: absolute;
cursor: pointer;
}

a:focus img{
width: 200%; 
height: 200%;
position: absolute;
opacity:1; 
z-index: 1; 
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px #000;
box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px #000; 
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s; 
-webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s; 
-moz-transition-duration: 2s;
-moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
-o-transition-duration: 2s;
-o-transition-delay: 0.3s;
cursor: default;
}

a:nth-child(3) img{
right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin-left:-50%;` and `margin-top:-50%;` to `a:focus img`:

```
a:focus img{
    width: 200%; 
    height: 200%;
    margin-left:-50%; /* line added */
    margin-top:-50%; /* line added */
    position: absolute;
    opacity:1; 
    z-index: 1; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px #000; 
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s; 
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s; 
    -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 2s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    cursor: default;
}
```

**Codepen [example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwXrdP)**

Comment: Because the the first child it's already `left :0;` now if you do add `margin-left:0;` for it, it will override the `margin-left:50%;` that we have added before on: `a:focus img`

Comment: You're welcome @AlexV . If you have some time to spare please consider marking my answer as correct =)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to try to make them appear to zoom in from the center of the gallery page you could change the position of the anchor element to `absolute` on focus, remove the positioning change on every third anchor and make a few changes to the a:focus image block.

```
a:focus {
  position:absolute;    
  left:30%;
  top:130px;
  z-index:1;
}
a:focus img{
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  margin:-50%;
  opacity:1; 
  z-index: 1; 
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px #000; 
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s; 
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s; 
  -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 2s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  cursor: default;
}
```

You can see the example in Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPeZmo).